# Shimano gear indicator stuck

Tags: shimano, shifter

I've got Shimano Deore shifters like the one on the picture
[image]
and XT rear derailleur.

The shifter and the derailleur work perfectly well, the chain and the cassette are quite new. Bit the problem is that the indicator is stuck on the "high gear" - at the right and is not moving.

Should I replace it or can it be fixed?

Comment: Please elaborate more on the meaning of "stuck" . Do you mean you cannot shift at all? Or it can't shift to particular gear? e.g. can't shift to high gear (low number) .

Comment: Is the indicator important to you? They're not necessary, and higher level groupsets don't include them, it's just a convenience thing (instead of looking down at the cassette). If it's important to you, it's worth opening it up to see if it's something obvious you can fix. There's chance you could mess up something required for shifting while you're in there, but if the plan was to throw them away anyway it can't hurt. If you look on youtube there seem to be several videos of people servicing similar shifters, although not this exact model.

Comment: @mootmoot as I said - the problem is just for the indicator

Comment: @JamieA well... no, I don't really need it, but it's a bit irritating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove those two screws visible in the picture and lift off the indicator. It may be that the mechanism to move the indicator has become dislodged.

You could, as I do remove the indicator completely. Sometimes underneath there is a blanking plate you can use to cover the hole. You don't need to see which gear you are in and it means you can move the lever closer to your brakes for a tidier bar layout.

Comment: I used to think the same, but the indicator is surprisingly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I opened an alfine shifter wrongly to change the inner cable recently.

The indicator mechanism is an incredibly lightweight and flimsy series of plastic levers and a cam.

The details will probably vary, but to fix it I had to take off the top cover (2 screws) and then used a length of sewing cotton looped around a lever to hold it back, while I reassembled the top cover... the fingers were too fat to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to take apart with just a couple of screws. I have those indicators but I took them off to arrange my cockpit better. If you're in the U.K. I don't mind posting them to you if you can't fix them.

If you were to remove them, you'll need the blanking plates to cover the mechanism underneath.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not in the U.K. I guess I'm going to remove it, never knew that it is so simple

Comment: If you go down the route of blanking them off, you might want to search the web for Shimano base hole covers. They will vary in shape of course depending on the model of shifter you have. Alternatively, just buy a new shifter. I bet you can get one dirt cheap on ebay.